# Streaming video files users have uploaded

Tags: java, video, streaming

We have a java web application where users can upload all kinds of files including any kind of video files. Now we want to allow them to stream these video files they own. So I need to make sure that they are the owner and then stream video. Also possibly stream a preview.

Do I need to convert these video files before streaming and where should I look to get started?

Answer (score 2):

The best video playback/encoding library I have ever seen is ffmpeg. It plays everything you throw at it. (It is used by MPlayer.) It is written in C but I found some Java wrappers.

FFMPEG-Java: A Java wrapper around ffmpeg using JNA.
jffmpeg: This one integrates to JMF.

Comment: So it can play these videos. But how could I stream these from my server?